# Power BI - Assigning values in one column to a new value in a new calculated column

Tags: excel, powerbi, analytics, dax

I have a column that consists of a few different values and I want to assign each unique value to a new term in a new calculated column. I think the 'if' function is used but not too sure.

Here's a mock up table of what I'm looking for - the 'Year' Column is what I would like to generate. [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix4r1.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your table name is "MyTable". Create a calculated column:

```
= SWITCH( 'MyTable'[Name],
           "A", 2019,
           "B", 2018,
           "C", 2017,
           "D", 2016)
```

You can also include a 'catch all" choice if you want, for values not on the list:

```
= SWITCH( 'MyTable'[Name],
               "A", 2019,
               "B", 2018,
               "C", 2017,
               "D", 2016,
                0)
```

which will display 0 (or BLANK, or whatever) if you have a name other than A, B, C, D.

SWITCH function is just a compact form of IF, whenever you have more than 2 choices.